# Responsive randomly generated elements

Tags: javascript, html, random, responsive-design, generated

I am trying to make a page that has randomly generated words in it, to function in a responsive way.

```
<head>
<style type='text/css'>

.box {
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
 }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function setDivPos() {
  for (i=1; i<=2; i++) {
     var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*1130);
     var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*722);
     document.getElementById('div'+i).style.left = x + 'px';
     document.getElementById('div'+i).style.top = y + 'px';
  }
</head>

<body onload='setDivPos();'>
<div id='div1' class='box'>ARCHIVE</div>
<div id='div2' class='box'>PERSPECTIVE</div>
</div>
</body>
```

The whole website is pretty much based in this algorithm. How can I make these randomly positioned objects within the area 1130x722, be placed within the screen size of each user. (responsive)

Comment: You need to ask a question.

Comment: I hope it is now more specific.

Comment: How are you calling setDivPos()?  And do you have two elements named div1 and div2?

Comment: Thank you honestly for trying to help twice, this is the whole code.

Comment: The problem you're going to have is if you don't want words to overlap then you need to keep track of the position of all previously appended words in your document.

Comment: I have no problem with words overlapping

Answer (score 0):

So I think you had everything about right.. It appears you forgot to create the div that wraps around the other two divs with the a relative div.  Check this fiddle [Example with a button](http://jsfiddle.net/7Xkgz/1/)

```
    <head>
    <style type='text/css'>

.box {
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
 }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function setDivPos() {
  for (i=1; i<=2; i++) {
     var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*1130);
     var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*722);
     document.getElementById('div'+i).style.left = x + 'px';
     document.getElementById('div'+i).style.top = y + 'px';
  }}
 //Add this script ending tag and your closing bracket on the function
</script>
</head>

<body onload='setDivPos();'>
<div id='div1' class='box'>ARCHIVE</div>
<div id='div2' class='box'>PERSPECTIVE</div>
<!-- This is commented out, but you should probably just delete the div -->
<!-- </div> -->
</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a way that works? In the fiddle program the components did what they would do regardless the container div. I also tried in a computer with largest screen than mine and it still did what it did before using the containg div.

Comment: Also, what does the onDomready do? I don't think it works since it just puts the words in the upper left part all together, but I am also interested to know what is it supposed to do (I think I used both suggestions correctly according to the fiddle script)

Comment: I put the extra div in there because in your code there was an extra div.  As far as the onDomready, I should have been a little more clear about that. I usually use JQuery and would have called that function inside of the $(document).ready.  Since I assumed I didn't have ability to grab the body in fiddle.  Check this fiddle that uses your onload in a different way. http://jsfiddle.net/7Xkgz/2/

Comment: Honestly, I see no difference between this and the previous.I tried the line you suggest in it, but the result is having the exact same result.

Comment: Ok so your issue was that you didn't close your script tag, and you didn't close your function inside of the script.  You have a closing div tag that has no beginning tag.  I adjusted my answer that should do what you need it to do.